# Sorting a belongsToMany relationship by an array of ids

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a model `Classroom` with a `belongsToMany` relationship. I want the order of its children to be eagerly determined by the array of ids already on the model e.g. `student_ids` has `[5,1,7,9,2]`.

In other words, whenever I get a `Classroom` it should always pick its `Students` in that order.

```
public function students()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class)->withTimestamps();
}
```

I've tried `sortBy('student_ids')` and `orderBy('student_ids')` which don't work — but I *have* managed to sort them by using something like this in my `Classroom` controller:

```
public function sortedStudents($ids)
{
    return $this->students()->sortBy(function ($student) use ($ids) {
        return array_search($student->id, $ids);
    });
}
```

This works but I need to pass in the `ids` after the fact. I would love to have it processed "by default" in the relationship itself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `withPivot` method to include the student ids which then allow ordering:

```
public function students()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class)->withPivot('student_id')->orderBy('classroom_student.student_id');
}
```

I assumed in this example your pivot table is named `classroom_student`.

Comment: Thanks. My pivot table is the default one. But the order is stored in the Classroom table, not on the relationship one. The reordering logic elsewhere affects just the `student_ids` of `Classrooms`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by your pivot table is the default one. By eloquent conventions, pivot tables are named alphabetically after the singular names of the tables they join. In this case `classroom_student` would be the standard naming convention.

Comment: I think I mean that by not passing a second argument into `belongsToMany()` it will follow the convention you mention (standard). But in this example does it not order by `student_id` every time? The order I want is a custom one set in the field `student_ids` on the `Classrooms` table. And each `Classroom` has different `student_ids` / varied orders.

Comment: Oh you're storing the student ids as a comma separated string directly on the `classrooms` table. In this case @TsaiKoga's answer is more pertinent. Personally, I would put a `sort_order` column on the pivot table and drop the `student_ids` column from `classrooms`. If that isnt feasible then TsaiKoga has the right idea.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if that would work though -- since a student may belong to many classrooms? Or I suppose it would work like a rank e.g. `sort_order` would mean priority e.g. 1 = first etc.

Comment: Students belonging to many classrooms won't be a problem since a separate record is created for each relationship between a student and a classroom. That way you can have total control over the ordering of the students on a per classroom basis. Then you would assign something like 1=first, 2=second, etc.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `orderByRaw` and `FIELD()` method to order by specific values sequence:

```php
public function students()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class)->withTimestamps()->orderByRaw("FIELD(id, 5,1,7,9,2)");
}
```